# How to customize template metadata.annotations.tags

Tags: templates, openshift, customization, openshift-origin

I've a very simple question: Is it possible to create some custom metadata.annotations.tags within openshift template (in order that they don't fall into the default "Uncategorized" if none is matching what you want) ? If yes how ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a new category unless you configure the web console as an admin for the whole cluster, but you can use an existing category. For example:

```
        "kind": "Template",
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "metadata": {
            "name": "notebook-builder",
            "annotations": {
                "openshift.io/display-name": "Jupyter Notebook Builder",
                "description": "Template for creating customised Jupyter Notebook images.",
                "iconClass": "icon-python",
                "tags": "python,jupyter"
            }
        },
```

Here the `python` tag results in it being added in the Python category.

See `tag` description for example in:

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-description

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for having taken the time to answer. My question was maybe not that clear. I know that you can attach your template to an existing category, I don't have any difficulty with that. What I'd like to be able to do is to create a not-yet-existing category and refer it with a tag in the template.
Yes, I'm cluster admin of our openshift instance and would like to configure that globally.

Comment: That section of the docs I referred you to has links to the documentation of how to do that. The two links were https://github.com/openshift/origin-web-console/blob/master/app/scripts/constants.js and https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/web_console_customization.html#configuring-catalog-categories but you should read the context in the documentation where links were. My only concern is that exactly how you did that changed not long back and so hoping the docs are up to date. I know someone who was doing it and docs didn't seem quite right.

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks exactly what I was looking for with extra stuff to be customized which is even better. Sorry I didn't read carefully enough at the doc to notice the link (and I read it a lot even before you mentioned it to me, I must be blind)